# Convergence of some integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I need to determine whether the following integrals converge:

1. $\displaystyle \int_1^{\infty} (x+\sqrt{x})^{-1}$
2. $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

For the first I think i need to use the comparison test but I'm not sure how and for the second I've worked it out using a substitution and found it has an answer but i"m not sure if this is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$\frac1{x+\sqrt x}\ge\frac1{2x}\;\;\;\text{...and compare with series}\;\;\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2n}\;\ldots ....$$

$$\int\frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=-\frac12\int\frac{(1-x^2)'dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=-\sqrt{1-x^2}+C\;\ldots$$

Comment: You missed a $\sqrt{}$ for the second integral, I guess.

Comment: I surely did, @Keba. Thanks, edited and corrected (the problems of trying to decypher question written without LaTeX...)

Comment: Next time just read the question more slowly and give me a chance to answer. ;)